# How can I transfer storage to from URL to Google Cloud when data is not publicly available?

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to transfer a large amount of data from a database I have access to with a username and password to a google cloud bucket. I tried the following but didn't succeed:

```
curl -s -u user:password URL/to/file.zip | gsutil cp - gs://bucket/file.zip
```

with the following output:

```
[2] 675
[3] 676
Copying from <STDIN>...
/ [1 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]
Operation completed over 1 objects.
[1]   Done                    curl -s -u user:password URL/to/file
[3]+  Done                    count=1
```

Can someone explain this output to me? (what does `[2] 675` and `[3] 676` mean?, does the 4th line suggest that there is only one file of 0.0 B to download? What does `[3]+ Done...` mean if there is only one file found?)

The link after `[1] Done ... curl -s -u user:pasword` is a link to the download (when I click it, a download starts on my local computer). The bucket now has a file named `file.zip` but doesn't contain any data. Why doesn't the data get uploaded to the bucket?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Tried to take the code apart and first use wget to download the file (because wget gives me information why it's not working). But this is where it seems to go wrong.

```
user@cloudshell:~ (project_ID)$ wget --user=<user> --password=<password> https://website.com/download/image?key=<key>&zip=<zip_name>.zip
[1] 1044
[2] 1045
--2020-02-07 11:47:35--  https://website.com/download/image?key=<key>
[2]+  Done                    count=1
user@cloudshell:~ (project_ID)$ Resolving website.com (website.com)... xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
Connecting to website.com (website.com)|xxx.xxx.xx.xxx|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403
2020-02-07 11:47:38 ERROR 403: (no description).
```

So, it seems to me that I can connect to the website, but something goes wrong with the HTTP request. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil` is the correct command to push data to Google Cloud Storage.

To simplify, you can break the the above command in two commands:
1. Command to read the data from database and put in a zip file
`curl -s -u user:password URL/to/file.zip -o /tmp/file.zip`

2. Once, the curl downloads the file to your local system, you can now upload it to GCS.
   `gsutil cp /tmp/file.zip gs://bucket/file.zip`

I have seen similar cases when using the pipe. I would suggest downloading the file to local using `curl` or `wget` then check the size and then push to GCS using `gsutil`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems to me like the answer is not complete yet?

Comment: It seems like he wanted to explain the usage of the Pipe. @Mira, could you check if the answer provided actually worked for you?

Comment: Mira- answer did went through due to some issue. I have updated it now.

Comment: I tried what you said, but can't download the file. I'm not sure why, could you take a look at my update? Thank you!

Comment: Mira - you are getting 403 error when trying to download data from your internal serve. 403 generally means the credentials you are using idoes not have permission to read the file. It doesnt look like any issue with interacting with GCP.
Can you make sure you use the right credentials to interact with your internal service?

Comment: I am sure my credentials are correct. The website I'm trying to download from creates a new download link every time I click on the download button, could it be that my download is connected to my session? If so, is there a way to include this in my curl request?

Comment: Hi Mira, have you been able to accomplish the transfer? If your download link is binded to your session this could be related with your app. talking about GCS, the download link should not be connected to your session.